# Why does my myTouch 4G lose battery so fast?

Tags: battery, battery-life, t-mobile, htc-mytouch

So I formatted my phone today. I have not used it, and it was at 100% this morning. No apps installed, the screen was only on for about 10 minutes. Yet when I go to check it now, about 12 hours later, its battery is at 13%. I got a new battery a few days ago, so the battery isn't worn out. My phone is a myTouch 4G from t-mobile. My android version on it is 2.3.4

Comment: Please check if one of the following is helpful for you: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/3052/what-does-battery-use-tell-and-how-is-it-implemented / http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/12347/what-can-cause-android-os-process-to-use-high-percentage-of-battery / http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/24675/battery-usage-by-certain-applications / http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/17382/how-can-i-find-out-what-causes-android-os-to-consume-battery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install BetterBatteryStats (from [Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.asksven.betterbatterystats) or from [XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=15869886&postcount=2), the latter is free) and see which is causing this.

If you're running the phone without a SIM card this might also be the reason:

Some phones aren't tested well if there's no SIM inserted (my old Xperia X8 is such a phone for example).

Narrow it down this way:

- Switch the phone to airplane mode (switches wifi/bluetooth/gsm off)
- Then re-enable wifi (plus maybe bluetooth) again. Just leave it for a while and see if it's better now.

Comment: I am running it with a SIM card, and need my wifi and stuff one.